# Depreciated Call -> Function wpdb::escape()

Tags: wpdb

I am getting lots of errors in my debug log:

> Depreciated Call -> Function wpdb::escape() - Use wpdb::prepare() or
>   esc_sql() instead

Instead of just turning off the debug log, I am trying to "fix" the "plugin at fault". Following are the lines using `wpdb::escape()`:

```
$wpdb->query(sprintf(
      "UPDATE %s SET %s = '%s' WHERE ID = %d"
      , $wpdb->posts
      , $wpdb->escape($key)
      , $wpdb->escape($visibility)
      , $post_id
));
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for helping people, not for doing other peoples work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

`prepare` works a bit differently than escape in that it works on whole strings and manages quoting as well.

```
$pat = "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET %s = %s WHERE ID = %d";
$qry = $wpdb->prepare(
  $pat,
  $key,
  $visibility,
  $post_id
);
$wpdb->query($qry);
```

You do not need to swap in the table name at all, and with `prepare` you can't swap it in because the table name will be quoted and the SQL will break.